# Составление регулярного выражения python

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Нужно создать регулярное выражение типа - слово [Сс]тена, потом идет либо число, либо несколько слов.
Пытался сделать что-то типа

```
pattern = r'\s*[Сс]тена\s[((\w{1,50}){1,10})(-?\d+)]'
```

Но не работает.
Мне нужно понять один момент:
В квадратные скобки передаются операторы и при поиске регулярного выражения выбирается один из элементов в квадратных скобках. А можно ли передать в квадратные скобки два шаблона, чтобы выбирался целый кусок, а не один символ. Мне нужно что-то вроде этого

```
pattern = r'[pattern1, pattern2]'
```

То есть мне нужно, чтобы выбиралась одна из групп операторов.
Я пытался сделать это с помощью круглых скобок, но это не сработало. Тогда мне хотелось бы также узнать, как правильно использовать круглые скобки и для чего они нужны

Поподробнее объясню, какой шаблон мне нужен:

**1)** Слово стена с заглавной или маленькой буквы и пробел(1+) (r'[Сс]тена\s+')

**2)** Далее выбирается один из двух шаблонов:

**2.1)** Либо несколько слов, разделённых пробелами

**2.2)** Либо какое-либо число, у которого в начале может стоять минус(r'-?\d+')

---

Допустим поиск по строке `"[anything-|=] Стена имя фамилия [anything=)=-(]"`

Должен дать строку `"Стена имя фамилия"`

Comment: приведите пример текста который вы обрабатываете и результат, который хотите получить...

Comment: `pattern = '(?:word1|word2)'`

Comment: [`(?i)стена\s{1}(?:\-?\d+|[\w\s]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/NJxY0L/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
strings = [
  "[anything-|=] Стена имя фамилия [anything=)=-(]",
  "[anything-|=] Стена -12 [anything=)=-(]",
  "[anything-|=] Стена 112 [anything=)=-(]"
]

pat = re.compile(r'(стена\s+(?:[-+]?\d+|[\w\s]+))', flags=re.I)

for s in strings:
    m = pat.search(s)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
```

результат:

```
Стена имя фамилия
Стена -12
Стена 112
```

Comment: Круглые скобки по бокам строки на мой взгляд не нужны, с ними при использовании метода split (разбиение строки по заданному шаблону), сама строка не исчезает.(Если вы поняли, что я сказал, попробуйте использовать метод split на ваших строках по вашему шаблону)

Comment: А вообще, спасибо большое.